# Disaster Recovery Setup On-prem to Azure 1.5TB VM

Tags: azure, disaster-recovery, azure-site-recovery

I have a 1.5 TB of Machine and I am trying to setup DR for that but the issue is that I  have only 300GB available on Hyper-V host. 
So ASR is not working.
Is there any way to use Network storage or any 3rd party tools that I can use to setup this?

Comment: You can check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/hyper-v-azure-support-matrix#hyper-v-host-storage

Comment: This says SAN and MPIO is supported but how we will be mapping ASR to use that one

Comment: SAN and MPIO - but not as network filesystems
It's supported if the Hyper-V volumes are on a SAN or MPIO disks not for NAS There is no any mapping option . we don't support SAN

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft “strongly recommendations” following options for protecting Hyper-V VMs

Preferred Option 1: We recommend customers use VMM to Azure for DR.

Preferred Option 2: If the customer for some reason wants to use site to site DR then our recommendation is to use Hyper-V replica based solution (ASR E2E)

Our guidance is that the above two are the best options for the customer from overall ease of use and support perspective as the end to end solution is Microsoft provided. We don't have another work around to support SAN based replication. However SAN storage on hosts is supported and customer can use regular Hyper-V to Azure scenario for protection of their VMs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/hyper-v-azure-support-matrix#hyper-v-host-storage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/tutorial-prepare-azure-for-hyperv

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.